# WPF. How to get a DrawingContext for a TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

I have a TextBlock. I want to draw inside it (within its *current* visual boundaries). I need DrawingContext for it.

How do I get DrawingContext?

*(MSDN says that any FrameworkElement is descendant from Visual and the Visual provides support for rendering.. But I cant quite find how exactly)*

Please note - this code will be called several time a second. I am looking for the most **efficient** solution (this is why I took on the DrawingContext in first place).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what I did: I wrote my own adorner, adorned the textblock, used OnRender to get DrawingContext, I am writing text directly to the adorner and invalidating Visual at each change.

The boost in performance (measured carefully with Ants profiler) is **4.5 times better** than writing text directly to the text block and even more so than binding string property.

Answer (score 0):

Why not overlay the TextBlock on a Canvas and draw to the Canvas ?

**XAML**

```
 <Grid>
    <Canvas Background='Orange'
            x:Name='drawingCanvas'
            Width='{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=textblock1, Mode=OneWay}'
            Height='{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=textblock1, Mode=OneWay}' />

    <TextBlock Text='Example'
               x:Name='textblock1'
               HorizontalAlignment='Center'
               VerticalAlignment='Center'
               FontSize='40' />
  </Grid>
```

**CODE**

```
public MainWindow() {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
      _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
      _timer.Start();
      _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
    }

    private void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      var newX = _bezierSeg.Point1.X + .1;
      _bezierSeg.Point1 = new Point(Math.Sin(newX) * 12, 0);
    }

    private DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer();

    private BezierSegment _bezierSeg = new BezierSegment();

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      var arcPath = new Path();
      var figure = new PathFigure();

      figure.StartPoint = new Point(0, 0);
      var Point1 = new Point(textblock1.ActualHeight, 0);
      var Point2 = new Point(textblock1.ActualWidth - 30, textblock1.ActualHeight - 20);
      var Point3 = new Point(textblock1.ActualWidth, textblock1.ActualHeight);

      _bezierSeg.Point1 = Point1;
      _bezierSeg.Point2 = Point2;
      _bezierSeg.Point3 = Point3;

      var myPathSegmentCollection = new PathSegmentCollection();

      myPathSegmentCollection.Add(_bezierSeg);
      figure.Segments = myPathSegmentCollection;

      var pathCollection = new PathFigureCollection();
      pathCollection.Add(figure);

      var pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
      pathGeometry.Figures = pathCollection;

      arcPath.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
      arcPath.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
      arcPath.StrokeThickness = 2;

      arcPath.Data = pathGeometry;
      drawingCanvas.Children.Add(arcPath);
    }
```

Comment: Just add elements to the canvas.  What do you need the drawing context for, that you can do my adding and animating elements?

Comment: you are not answering my question

Comment: Well,  if you have a perf reason for needing drawing context, then ignore my answer.

Comment: BoppityBop - the @WaltRitcher gave you a correct answer. I suppose you looking something of this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748838(v=vs.110).aspx  but Walt Ritcher answer is correct one. Don't abuse WPF. TextBlock is not created for drawing on it